# ¿Borrar Columna en Mysql con Python?

Tags: python

Mi duda es que necesito hacer un menu:

Que pida al usuario por teclado el id del producto que desea borrar.
He probado con este codigo pero no me funciona.

**Código:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
if opcion==3:
       Codigo =input("Inserta El Codigo Del Fabricante Que Desea Usted Borrar: ")
       sql2 = "DELETE FROM fabricante WHERE Codigo = (%s)"
       val2 = (str(Codigo))
       mycursor.execute(sql2,val2)
       tienda.commit()
       print(mycursor.rowcount, "Total Borrado")
```

Comment: Buenas, puedes agregar los pasos anteriores para realizar la ejecución ?? desde la lectura del opcion 3, para entrar al IF

Comment: *no me funciona* que sucede? Por que no funciona? Sin esa informacion cualquier respuesta es pura especulacion.

Comment: Una [columna](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columna_(base_de_datos)) es una entidad estructural de una tabla de la BD, no se puede borrar a la ligera sin hacer un `ALTER TABLE`. Supongo te refieres es a una **Fila**, o sea a un **registro** de la tabla.